# Obtaining directory change notifications for media portable devices

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, media-player

We can find the change in directory by using the `FindFirstChangeNotification()` and `FindNextChangeNotification()` functions like :

```
FindFirstChangeNotification( 
      lpDir,                         // directory to watch 
      FALSE,                         // do not watch subtree 
      FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME); // watch file name changes
```

But in Windows there is no actual path for media portable devices like Android phones, camera, etc. Then how can we track the changes 
(**create,copy,delete,rename**) done on these devices in C++?

Comment: for obtaining directory change need use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` and what you mean under `actual path for media portable devices` ?

Comment: [SHChangeNotifyRegister](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120.aspx) and friends work on PIDLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These media devices only exist at the shell level, they do not allow direct access to their filesystem (and even if they did, it might be ext3 or some other filesystem not supported by Windows). You cannot use `FindFirstChangeNotification` and other functions in kernel32, you must use the functions in shell32 and shlwapi that supports IShellItem, IShellFolder and [PIDLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090(v=vs.85).aspx).

To create a PIDL you can call [`SHParseDisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236(v=vs.85).aspx) if you know the path (`shell:::{something}\{something}`) or `SHGetDesktopFolder` + `IShellFolder::EnumObjects` to walk the entire shell namespace.

Sometimes it is possible to find the shell: path by right clicking the **item** in the Explorer breadcrumb-bar and selecting "Copy address".

When you have an absolute PIDL to the device folder you can call [`SHChangeNotifyRegister`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120.aspx).